# Render .Rmd inside shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown, render

I'm trying to render an .Rmd file and show it inside my shiny App. The Rmd is a function of app inputs/outputs. I have two problems:
1-Each new paragraph in the "Rmd" file shows as a new box in the final product.
2- my HTML output starts from the middle of the page, rather than left side.

A reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("rmd_output"),
  selectInput("word", "Word", c("line", "LINE"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$rmd_output <- renderUI({
    HTML(readLines(rmarkdown::render(input = "file.Rmd",
                                     output_format = rmarkdown::html_document(),
                                     quiet = TRUE,
                                     runtime = "shinyrmd"
    )))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the `file.rmd` looks like this:

````html
---
output: html_document2
runtime: shiny
---
<style>
.block-class {
  width: 150%;
  margin: 10px 0;  /* Reset horizontal margin to 0 */
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
</style>

## Executive Summary ##
### Background ###
```{r, echo=F, comment='', class.output="block-class"}
library(glue)
my_word <- input$word

glue("First {my_word}
     second {my_word}?
     \n third {my_word}?
     <br> fourth {my_word}?")
glue("Second or fifth {my_word}?")
```
````

The result for me shows as:
[image: html result]